# ILOG OPL: Export Model to .lp File

Tags: model, export, ilog

I want to export my .mod file to a .lp file, to use it in a java program. I have a extra .dat file, that contains the declarations for the variables in the .mod file.

If i now want to export the model with opl:

```
oplrun -e planung.lp planung.mod
```

it gaves me the errors, that the variables in the .mod file are not defined. So it seems that opl coudnt find my .dat file, but it is in the same directory as the .mod file.

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the data file in command line as well, e.g.:

```
oplrun -e planung.lp planung.mod planung.dat
```